# Why do we use pigeonhole principle to prove equality?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I often found that to prove $2$ variables are equal,  pigeonhole principle is used. For example see the following text:

> Let $F$ be any family of type $t_{i, j}$ ... and so the family $F$ is mapped into a family $F'$ of edges of type
> $t_{r, s}, r\geq i, s\geq j$. By the pigeonhole principle,  $r = i$ and
> $s = j$, from which the lemma follows [(pages 120, 121, 122)](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cmh/distribution/books0/chapter4.pdf).

We can directly say $r = i$ and $s = j$, why $r > i$ and $s> j$ was assumed and  pigeonhole principle is used?

**Added:**

If $F$ is a family of edges of type $t_{i,j}$, then ($F)_k$ denotes the set of $j$ vertices of $V_k$
incident to the family, and $(F)_{k+1}$ denotes the set of $i$ vertices in $V_{k+1}$ incident to the family.

If you look at the definition on page 121 (second last paragraph):$F$ is a family of edges of type $t_{i,j}$, then ($F)_k$ denotes the set of $j$ vertices of $V_k$ incident to the family, and $(F)_{k+1}$ denotes the set of $i$ vertices in $V_{k+1}$ incident to the family. That is why if a permutation fixes  $(F)_k$ it also fixes  $(F)_{k+1}$ (AND VICE VERSA, to my understanding), because of the adjacency.

Similarly, if a  permutation $\pi$ moves $(F)_k$ consisting $j$ vertices to another $(F')_k$ (which also consists $j$ vertices), then because of the adjacency defined,   $\pi$ moves the incident $(F)_k$ of $i$ vertices, to another $(F')_k$  of $i$ vertices.

In this situation, why would you consider the case $j = |(F)_k| < |(F')_k| = s$ and $i = |(F)_{k+1}| <  |(F')_{k+1}| = r$, instead of directly equating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are trying to *prove* that $\alpha$ maps a family $F$ of type $t_{i,j}$ to a family of the same type - so no, we cannot *assume* that $F'$ has the same type.

What we know is that $\alpha$ maps $(F)_k$ into $(F')_k$, so $j = |(F)_k| \le |(F')_k| = s$. Similarly, since $\alpha$ maps $(F)_{k+1}$ into $(F')_{k+1}$, we have $i = |(F)_{k+1}| \le |(F')_{k+1}| = r$. This is what tells us that $F'$ has some type $t_{r,s}$ with $i \le r$ and $j \le s$. (But as of this moment, we haven't ruled out the possibility that $(F')_k$ has other vertices *in addition* to the $j$ that are the image of $(F)_k$ under $\alpha$; this is why we cannot immediately say that $j=s$. Similarly for $i$ and $r$.)

The argument to show $i=r$ and $j=s$ is not pigeonhole, exactly, though it has the same flavor. Let $U$ be the union of all families of types $t_{r,s}$ with $r+s > i+j$. We've shown that $\alpha$ maps every family contained in $U$ into some other family contained in $U$. So actually, $\alpha$ must simply permute $U$ somehow.

Therefore $F'$ cannot have a type $t_{r,s}$ with $r+s > i+j$: otherwise, it would be in $U$, so its preimage would be in $U$. Since we know $r+s \ge i+j$, we conclude $r+s = i+j$, so $r=i$ and $s=j$.

Comment: I have added more to the post. Let me write it here again.

If you look at the definition on page 121 (second last paragraph):$F$ is a family of edges of type $t_{i,j}$, then ($F)_k$ denotes the set of $j$ vertices of $V_k$ incident to the family, and $(F)_{k+1}$ denotes the set of $i$ vertices in $V_{k+1}$ incident to the family. That is why if a permutation fixes  $(F)_k$ it also fixes  $(F)_{k+1}$ (AND VICE VERSA, to my understanding), because of the adjacency.

Comment: Similarly, if a  permutation $\pi$ moves $(F)_k$ consisting $j$ vertices to another $(F')_k$ (which also consists $j$ vertices), then because of the adjacency defined,   $\pi$ moves the incident $(F)_k$ of $i$ vertices, to another $(F')_k$  of $i$ vertices.
In this situation, why would you consider the case $j = |(F)_k| < |(F')_k| = s$ and $i = |(F)_{k+1}| <  |(F')_{k+1}| = r$, instead of directly equating?

I am not saying you are wrong, I am just trying to understand.

Comment: We can imagine that a permutation $\alpha$ might move the vertices of $(F)_k$ to a subset of $(F')_k$ consisting of $j$ out of $s$ vertices - and there are other vertices in $(F')_k$ that are not in the image of $(F)_k$ under $\alpha$. We are trying to prove that this does not happen.